# How to track button click in Veeva clm using callClickStream

Tags: clickstream, veeva

I am creating a veeva CLM and I have slides that contain buttons whose clicks I would like to track, for example I would like to know the name of the clicks that there are on the "References" button of slide 1

Any help please ?